# image editor component for my web site

Tags: asp.net, image

I know this has been asked before, but I am hoping that there are more options available now.
I am looking for a nice simple image editing plugin that I can include in my document imaging system.

It doesn't need serious photoshop type functionality, just the basics like zooming,cropping,resizing,flipping and rotating.

Doesn't have to be a freebie component, but I would prefer there to not be runtime licenses because there will e multiple implementations of our product.

btw - website is in ASP.Net

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 0):

We use CuteEditor from www.cutesoft.net, its a great html editor and has a good uploading and image editing, I think these can be used outside the editor: see: http://cutesoft.net/forums/9329/ShowPost.aspx